# How to call querySelector for different class?

Tags: javascript, web-parts, queryselector

Need to make a webpart which gets data from API in JSON format. I generate a table from JSON with projects number. Then I change each *td* to link with class="*project_number*".
[image]

Now each position has it's specific class. No I need each link to direct to project details ot url like: `https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/protocollines?protocolNo=PR0002`

I don't know what parameter should I place in querySelector to have addEventListener for each link.

`document.querySelector("???").addEventListener('click', *function*);`

```
  function changeToLink(){
    var tableCells = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('td'));
    var i;    
    var proNo = "PR0";
        
     for (i=0; i<tableCells.length; i++ && isContains == true) {
      var proFromArray = tableCells[i].innerHTML;
      var isContains = proFromArray.includes(proNo);    

      if(isContains == true){
        var tdElement = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i];
        console.log('Profrom: ' + proFromArray);
        tdElement.innerHTML = `<a class="${proFromArray}" href='https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/protocollines?protocolNo=${proFromArray}'>${proFromArray}</a>`
      }
     }
    
  }
 document.querySelector(`??`).addEventListener('click', *function*);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this.

Option 1

You could create the anchor elements using JS, and add the onclick event when you create each one, like:

```
// inside the if(isContains == true){
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = proFromArray;
a.href = `https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/protocollines?protocolNo=${proFromArray}`;
a.textContent = proFromArray;
a.onclick = this.getJsonData;
```

I created a Fiddle to demonstrate how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/brettnolf/f3xd7ag1/

Option 2

Now, if you *need* to create it in the form of a string and later call `querySelector` on what you created, you could add the same class to each anchor tag:

```
tdElement.innerHTML = `<a class="${proFromArray} pro-elem" href='https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/protocollines?protocolNo=${proFromArray}'>${proFromArray}</a>`
```

Then add the event listener, like:

```
var pros = document.querySelectorAll('.pro-elem')
for (var i = 0; i < pros.length; i++) {
    pros[i].addEventListener(this.getJsonData);
}
```

Option 3

If both of those solutions are out of the question, you could use a query selector wildcard and add the event listener similar to the above:

```
var pros = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=PR0]')
// or if you wanted to be really specific:
// document.querySelectorAll('td a[class^=PR0]')
for (var i = 0; i < pros.length; i++) {
    pros[i].addEventListener(this.getJsonData);
}
```

You can see this last solution in action if you pull up Chrome dev tools here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll and enter `document.querySelectorAll('[class^=title]')` in the Console.

Note that the last two options will only work *after* the elements have been added to the DOM. In the first option, you add the listener when you create the element, so you do it on the fly.